# Apache Spark SQL BLOB datatype

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-spark

While programming implementation with Apache Spark, I faced the problem processing a table with BLOB datatype.

```
document_id | content
          2   0x123sa..
        ......
```

`org.apache.spark.sql.Row` provides support for different sql datatypes, but i've not found a BLOB type:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTS").map(row -> {
   String documentName = row.getString(0);
   Blob documentContents = row.???
   ....
}
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call `printSchema()` on the `SchemaRDD` (Spark 1.2.0 or earlier) or `DataFrame` (Spark 1.3.0) returned by the `sql()` call to check for sure what you're getting -- a good technique to use whenever you're confused about the schema. (It's up to the implementation of the database connector to decide how to map the type.) The most likely option is `BinaryType`, which would look like:

```
root
 |-- document_id string (nullable = ...)
 |-- content binary (nullable = ...)
```

In which case you should be able to extract it using

```
row.getAs[Array[Byte]](1)
```

Comment: How to convert this `row.getAs[Array[Byte]](1) ` to Java?

Answer (score 0):

In spark2, I get it by using Java byte [] as shown bellow :

byte[] fileContent = (byte[]) r.get(0);